# Android's GPS invocation

Tags: android, gps

I wrote an android application which record information about the GPS location finding. so I record the following variables :
1- time when GPS starting
2- time when GPS stopping
3- first fix time
but I have two questions :
A) what is the meaning of the first fix time ?
B) After fix time and before GPS stopping time, what is the android doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time To First Fix is a measure of the time it takes for the GPS receiver to get a satellite signal and to calculate Lat and Lon points. (the crossing of these lines in the "fix"). Each fix has a mathematical margin of error calculated by math that's too hard for me. Somethings about time dilution, geometric dilution, atmospheric conditions messing with the signal and even relativity. Anyways, when an acceptably accurate "fix" is achieved that's when you get that GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED.